# Unhandled Promise rejection: Timeout ; Zone: Recaptcha

Tags: javascript, angular

I added recaptcha on my angular page.  after i resolve the recaptcha, there seems to be error after about 10 sec. Unhandled Promise rejection: Timeout ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Timeout undefined.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tdec-captcha',
  templateUrl: './tdec-captcha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tdec-captcha.component.scss']
})
export class TdecCaptchaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){

  }

  relolved = function (event: any) {
    //this.re_Captcha = event
    if (event !== null) {
      this.apiService.re_Captcha = true;    
    }  
  }
}
<div class="overlay">
  <div #captcha>
    <re-captcha class="captcha" (resolved)="relolved($event)" siteKey="6wekif9g88gwZAAasYncf6GHj5F6dvpkQ_90000Bp
"></re-captcha> 
  </div>enter code here
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/123

Answer (score 1):

In search of a solution to the error, I noticed that by adding the following entry to the component, the error disappears.

```
import { RecaptchaComponent } from 'ng-recaptcha';

ngOnInit() {
    RecaptchaComponent.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an internal issue with ng-recaptcha package.

If you can - ignore it. Add this error to an allowlist in your e2e tests or frontend monitoring software.

Otherwise, you can override the `ngOnDestroy` method of `RecaptchaComponent` manually (or create a component fork). Please be aware, that this **is a temporary and pretty bad fix that might put you in a very unfortunate position when upgrading component versions!** Nevertheless, here's approximate code for that:

```
// somewhere in your "main.ts"
import { RecaptchaComponent } from 'ng-recaptcha';
RecaptchaComponent.prototype.ngOnDestroy = function() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

(P.S. Taken from [ng-recaptcha tag  causes error “zone.js: Unhandled Promise rejection” when route changes](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/123#issuecomment-426112101))